# issues while running an sql statement

Tags: mysql

I am running this Stored Procedure and getting an Error from Mysql

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `usp_bk_mailsettings_insert`(OUT _mID bigint,
    _username varchar(255),
    _msendusername varchar(255),
    _alais varchar(255),
    _password varchar(255),
    _MailServer varchar(255),
    _Port varchar(100),
    _err varchar(255))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `bk_mailsettings`(`username`,`msendusername`,`alais`,`password`,`MailServer`,`Port`,`err`,`active`)
VALUES (_username,_msendusername,_alais,_password,_MailServer,_Port,_err,0);

select last_insert_id() into _mID;
END
```

Error is:

> Error Executing Database Query.
>       OUT or INOUT argument 1 for routine bakeryshop.usp_bk_mailsettings_insert is not a variable or NEW
>   pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger

I am confused what is wrong, everything seems fine and I checked so many forums and posts but not a valid answer as to how this can be fixed.

Comment: Use block quotes for copy content.

Answer (score 0):

With this stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS usp_bk_mailsettings_insert//

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_bk_mailsettings_insert (
    OUT _mID bigint,
    _username varchar(255),
    _msendusername varchar(255),
    _alais varchar(255),
    _password varchar(255),
    _MailServer varchar(255),
    _Port varchar(100),
    _err varchar(255)
    )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `bk_mailsettings`(`username`,`msendusername`,`alais`,`password`,`MailServer`,`Port`,`err`,`active`)
    VALUES (_username,_msendusername,_alais,_password,_MailServer,_Port,_err,0);

    SELECT last_insert_id() INTO _mID;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

You can call:

```
CALL usp_bk_mailsettings_insert(@out, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7)
```

Then the result `@out` will be available with:

```
SELECT @out;
```

->

```
mysql> SELECT @out;
+------+
| @out |
+------+
|  123 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you want the stored procedure to return the result directly, you need to use:

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS usp_bk_mailsettings_insert//

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_bk_mailsettings_insert (
    _username varchar(255),
    _msendusername varchar(255),
    _alais varchar(255),
    _password varchar(255),
    _MailServer varchar(255),
    _Port varchar(100),
    _err varchar(255)
    )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `bk_mailsettings`(`username`,`msendusername`,`alais`,`password`,`MailServer`,`Port`,`err`,`active`)
    VALUES (_username,_msendusername,_alais,_password,_MailServer,_Port,_err,0);

    SELECT last_insert_id();
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Then call it with:

```
CALL usp_bk_mailsettings_insert(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7)
```

->

```
+------------------+
| last_insert_id() |
+------------------+
|              123 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```